# How to add shapefile to dataframe from Python toolbox (ArcMap 10.4)

Tags: arcpy, layers

Does anyone know how I can add a shapefile to my current dataframe?

I have only been able to find examples that use a path for the shapefile.

```
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]  

    PWshed = arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion("Wshed", "PWshed", "SIMPLIFY")

    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, PWshed,"TOP")
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the question to specify the version of ArcGIS in use.  You'll also need to further clarify what you mean by "geoprocessed object" (not having the object in question in the code block makes the code useless)

Comment: I am trying to add the object "PWshed" to my dataframe

Comment: Are you ***sure*** the output is a shapefile? Without a suffix, and with no indication of the default workspace, I'd expect a file geodatabase result.

Comment: i dont know what the Object is. My problem is that when i run the commands as a script the result layer is added automaticly to TOC, but when i run as a Python toolbox i cant find any of the result Objects.

Comment: The [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm) doesn't show that tool returning anything. You should probably put more effort into reliably naming the output (second parameter), then you can use the path, as all the examples show.

Answer (score 1):

Shapefile or Featureclass cannot be imported directly into the MXD. We need to create a FeatureLayer for the particular dataset first. I hope following will be helpful:

```
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]  

PWshed = arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion("Wshed", "PWshed", "SIMPLIFY")

# Creating the Feature Layer for PWshed
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(PWshed, "PWshed_layer")

# Creating the Layer object from the PWshed
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(PWshed)

arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer,"TOP")

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```